# application textbox display currency in $ instead of R

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below code shows amount in Rands when i run from my machine but when published it displays same in $

```
TxtActualYTDgros1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", Actual_YTD_Gross);
 TxtSpndPlan1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", Spend_Plan_YTD);
 TxtVarience1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", Variance_Value);
```

Comment: Your locale must be set wrongly.

Comment: u have to use CultureInfo to get the region specific formats.

Comment: Thank u guys, it displays correctly nw but the formating is still messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify explicitly South African culture as a fromat provider to keep the same currency across all machines.

```
var saCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("af-ZA");
TxtActualYTDgros1.Text = String.Format(saCulture ,"{0:C}", Actual_YTD_Gross);
TxtSpndPlan1.Text = String.Format(saCulture, "{0:C}", Spend_Plan_YTD);
TxtVarience1.Text = String.Format(saCulture, "{0:C}", Variance_Value);
```

Comment: i tried an it under lines"var" and "CultureInfo" is ther a name space i have to use?

Comment: Hi,I used this but "var" is still underlined in red              var saCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("af-ZA");

Comment: Thanks I got it, u da BOOOOOs